# How to highlight terms in an output that has a live update?

Tags: bash, grep, ffmpeg, ack

I'm doing a loop over ffmpeg to convert a bunch of videos, and I would like to highlight some terms in ffmpeg's output. But the solution I tried always made the live progress of the conversion disappear.

What I have tried is mainly to redirect stderr to stdout, and grep or ack like this (ffmpeg's command is simplified for readability) :

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 ouput.mkv 2>&1 | ack --passthru --color "pcm_s16le|aac"`

or

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 ouput.mkv 2>&1 | grep -E "pcm_s16le|aac|$"`
(note the `|$` hack that allow to match everything without coloring it, acting like a passthrough)

And what I mean by live progress info is the line that look like this :

`frame=190 fps=3.7 q=-0.0 size=308kB time=06:08.66 bitrate=677kbits/s speed=0.17x`

So, is there a way to highlight some words that output, *and* keep the live progress ?

Comment: Can you verify that your patterns are correctly defined? If you save the `ffmpeg` output to a file and then run the `ack` or `grep` commands, does it produce the output you are expecting?

Comment: Yes, the patterns work. Even in the console I see the right words highlighted. The issue is that I don't know how that progress info seems to not be seen by grep nor ack. You can see it yourself with `ffmpeg 2>&1 | grep -E "ffmpeg|$"` for example.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're seeing is almost certainly due to the progress info being printed with CR (carriage-return, ASCII 13) line endings, instead of the traditional Unix LF (line-feed, ASCII 10). This is done to allow each new progress update to overprint the last.

Unfortunately, this means the *entire set* of progress updates looks to `grep`, `ack` and all other line-oriented tools as a single line. That's why they seem to "lock up" and print nothing until `ffmpeg` finishes, and I can't think of a similar highlighting tool that operates on anything but a standard Unix line basis.

You *could* try something like:

```
ffmpeg ... | tr \\015 \\012 | grep ...
```

which transforms all CRs to LFs. This lets `grep` *et al* see each progress update as a separate line, at the cost of also *seeing* each update as a separate line, filling your terminal:

```
frame=   85 fps=0.0 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.79 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=7.55x    
frame=  129 fps=129 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:05.65 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=5.64x    
frame=  172 fps=111 q=28.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:07.42 bitrate= 282.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=4.81x    
frame=  213 fps=104 q=28.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:09.17 bitrate= 457.3kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=4.49x    
frame=  254 fps= 99 q=28.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:10.85 bitrate= 386.3kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=4.22x    
frame=  295 fps= 96 q=28.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:12.56 bitrate= 500.7kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=4.08x    
frame=  333 fps= 93 q=28.0 size=    1024kB time=00:00:14.14 bitrate= 593.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=3.94x    
frame=  382 fps= 93 q=28.0 size=    1024kB time=00:00:16.19 bitrate= 518.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=3.93x    
frame=  428 fps= 93 q=28.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:18.11 bitrate= 579.0kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=3.92x    
frame=  473 fps= 92 q=28.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:20.00 bitrate= 628.9kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=3.91x    
frame=  519 fps= 92 q=28.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:21.93 bitrate= 573.8kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed= 3.9x    
frame=  567 fps= 92 q=28.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:23.91 bitrate= 613.9kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=3.89x    
frame=  601 fps= 90 q=28.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:25.32 bitrate= 662.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed= 3.8x    
frame=  637 fps= 89 q=28.0 size=    2304kB time=00:00:26.83 bitrate= 703.3kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=3.75x    
frame=  684 fps= 89 q=28.0 size=    2304kB time=00:00:28.77 bitrate= 655.9kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=3.74x    
frame=  720 fps= 84 q=-1.0 size=    2924kB time=00:00:30.01 bitrate= 798.0kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed= 3.5x    
...
```

You'd probably also want to disable stdio buffering between the components in this pipeline for maximum responsivness:

```
stdbuf -o0 ffmpeg ... 2>&1 | stdbuf -i0 -o0 tr \\015 \\012 | stdbuf -i0 -o0 grep ...
```

Comment: That's a nice idea. Doing it with sed would allow to do the reverse after the grep, and keep the \r.
Except doing a grep or ack after the tr command is really weird. Looks like flush issues. And I tried with sed, it didn't output anything :/

Comment: @Cqoicebordel "And I tried with sed, it didn't output anything" Well, `sed` is also line-oriented. so it can't do `tr`'s job in this scenario.

Comment: @Cqoicebordel As for "flush issues", I just added a note to my answer about disabling stdio buffering.

Comment: The flush issues are indeed solved. But the grep command don't seem to work after that. the `ack` one works, but I can't do anything after it, even just adding `> file.txt` doesn't work (empty file). So, there is something weird, and I don't know what is it :/

Comment: @Cqoicebordel What does your command line look like? I tested with `stdbuf -o0 ffmpeg -i test.mkv test.mp4 2>&1 | stdbuf -i0 -o0 tr \\015 \\012 | stdbuf -i0 -o0 grep -E --color=always "pcm_s16le|aac|$" | stdbuf -i0 tee file.txt`. It displayed the entire `ffmpeg` output very responsively, and `file.txt` even captured all of `grep`'s highlighting.

Comment: It was the same except for `--color=always` for the grep, and I didn't use tee, just did a `> file.txt` at the end of the `ack` command (as written above). And of course the ffmpeg command was different. The color always helped.  
So, now, I try to add a step at the end : `stdbuf -i0 -o0 sed -E "s/x\x20+\x0A/\x0D/m"` ('x' to match the speed item). You say it's not possible because of sed being line oriented ? Is there any way to do that another way ?

Comment: I tried to add `stdbuf -i0 -o0 sed -u -e "N;s/  \x0A/\r/"` after the ffmpeg, but it works only on half the lines, and doesn't update the other half, just waits to have two lines in the buffer to print them, so, no cigar.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

- Adrian's answer is very helpful, but I lost the dialogue, the prompt

  ```
  File 'output.mkv' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N]
  ```
- With the tool `vialog`, that is using `xterm` and its log file, I could make it work all the way

  ```
  stdbuf -o0 vialog ffmpeg -t 10 -i input.mp4 output.mkv |
  stdbuf -i0 -o0 tr -s '\015' '\012' |
  stdbuf -i0 -o0 grep --color -e 'time' -e 'speed' -e 'Audio:' -e 'Video:' -e '$'
  ```

  - with the dialogue in the `xterm` window
  - with high-lighting in the terminal window, where `vialog` is started (which makes it a console window of `xterm`),
- You find the tool `vialog` via this link,

  [Wake me up when a [slow] command line process wants my attention?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106774/wake-me-up-when-a-slow-command-line-process-wants-my-attention)

  You may want to modify `vialog` to do more exactly what you want.